# SAP Hybris impex import issues

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I'have an issues when import an impex on console administration HAC of SAP, issues is the below:

```
INSERT_UPDATE PlanogramStore;planogramCode[unique=true];storeRef[unique=true];branchOffice;endValidity[dateformat='dd-MM-yyyy', unique=true]
,,,,Exception : line 4: cannot create PlanogramStore with values ItemAttributeMap[ registry:  null, type: <null>, data: {storeref=952, branchoffice=1, endvalidity=null, planogramcode=15713} ] due to Argument mismatch trying to set value '1' for attribute de.hybris.platform.jalo.GenericItem.branchOffice (got java.lang.String, expected de.hybris.platform.store.BaseStore)., transaction rolled back because it has been marked as  rollback-only, Exception : line..
```

the item-core is this:

```
<itemtype code="PlanogramStore" autocreate="true" generate="false">
            <deployment table="PlanogramStore" typecode="21076"/>
            <attributes>
                <attribute type="java.lang.Integer" qualifier="planogramCode">
                    <modifiers/>
                    <persistence type="property"/>
                </attribute>
                
                <attribute type="java.lang.String" qualifier="storeRef">
                    <modifiers/>
                    <persistence type="property"/>
                </attribute>
            
                <attribute type="java.lang.String" qualifier="branchOffice">
                    <modifiers/>
                    <persistence type="property"/>
                </attribute>
                <attribute type="java.util.Date" qualifier="endValidity">
                    <modifiers/>
                    <persistence type="property"/>
                </attribute>
            </attributes>
            <indexes>
                <index name="PlanogramStoreIndex">
                    <key attribute="endValidity"/>
                    <key attribute="planogramCode"/>
                    <key attribute="storeRef"/>
                </index>
            </indexes>
        </itemtype>
```

Impex is below:

```
INSERT_UPDATE PlanogramStore;planogramCode[unique=true];storeRef[unique=true];branchOffice;endValidity[dateformat='dd-MM-yyyy', unique=true]
;15713;244;1
;15713;814;1
;15713;952;1
```

How is the problem? And how resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever create the branchOffice property as type "Basestore" before? going by the error, your system thinks it needs to be a basestore. Mosty likely you forgot to run an update system?

Comment: @Yoni I not ever create branchOffice like type "BaseStore" and I run update system and also initialize but nothing change.

Comment: Try to check through backoffice -> types -> search for your PlanogramStore, and check what the type of the property branchOffice is

Comment: @Yoni Ok I've check and type of property is java.lang.String

Comment: @Yoni could the problem be related to the typegroup? For these 4 entities I declared a typegroup named "Assortment". An impex related to the PlanogramCategoryAnag entity is imported correctly, the problem is only on the impex PlanogramStore.

Comment: please check is there any orphaned type system,if it's there please clean it and execute.
If it's not there just do simple restart and execute the impex

Comment: @RaushanKumar how can I do? can you explain to me in more detail please? Thanks

Comment: hac-->maintenance-->Type System If there any orphan types please clean it

Comment: @RaushanKumar nothing change. Same issue

Comment: To be sure it's not old data, you could try and use a different typecode in the deployment? (requires an update system after changing it)

Comment: I resolve it, I have stash the change and run ant all initialize, I re-write the code and run again ant all initialize and it work